# Raise 404 and continue the URL chain

Tags: django, django-urls, django-views, django-signals

I've got a URLs pattern like this:

```
urlpatterns = (
    url(r'^$', list_titles, name='list'),
    url(r'^(?P<tag>[a-z\-0-9]+?)/$', list_titles, name='filtered-list'),
    url(r'^(?P<title>\S+?)/$', show_title, name='title'),
)
```

The `filtered-list` and `title` match the same things.

If there is an available list of things matching the `tag` in `filtered-list`, I want `list_titles` to fire off. But if there isn't a matching `tag`, I want to bubble that back to the URL processor so `show_title` fires off.

If there's no matching title, I'll raise a proper 404 there.

I know I can do this from inside the view...but it's a bit smelly having to hard-wire the process into the view. I'd like the URL order to decide what gets chosen first and what it hands off to.

Answer (score 64, accepted):

This is certainly view logic; all urls.py is for is for matching URL patterns, not performing validation. You can use the [`Http404`](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/http/views/#the-http404-exception) exception to handle this.

```
from django.http import Http404

def detail(request, poll_id):
    try:
        p = Poll.objects.get(pk=poll_id)
    except Poll.DoesNotExist:
        raise Http404
    return render_to_response('polls/detail.html', {'poll': p})
```

Alternatively, you may find the [`get_object_or_404`](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/http/shortcuts/#get-object-or-404) or [`get_list_or_404`](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/http/shortcuts/#get-list-or-404) methods, which shorten it up a bit.

---

Promised edit follows. Not exactly what you're looking for, but...

```
urlpatterns = (
    url(r'^$', list_titles, name='list'),
)

if 1=1: # Your logic here
    urlpatterns += ( url(r'^$', list_titles, name='list'), )

urlpatterns += (
    url(r'^(?P<title>\S+?)/$', show_title, name='title'),
    url(r'^spam/$', spam_bar),
    url(r'^foo/$', foo_bar),
}
```

Comment: thanks for get_list_or_404 but this isn't an answer so much to my question. I'm saying if I can't get a list of titles based on the URL, I want the URL to be re-evaluated through the rest of the URLs.

Comment: Hmm...I see. Your original question wasn't terribly clear. Remember that the urls.py is just Python code, so you can do some sort of validation there. Give me a minute and I'll edit my answer.

Comment: `raise Http404` should probably be `raise Http404()`: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/http/views/#the-http404-exception

Comment: I know this answer is super old, but the `if 1=1` just stroke me hard. It is so wrong in many levels.

Comment: This is not a valid answer. URL lookup does not continue after raising Http404