# Redirects clashing with URL patterns Django

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, django-urls, django-1.8

I'm trying to get Django's redirects app working, it works with some of the redirects I have in the database, but not all of them.

The ones that match with one of my url patterns 404 without redirecting, the rest are fine.

```
urlpatterns = [
    ...
    url(r'^(?P<category>[-\w]+)/$', views.SubCategoryListView.as_view(),
        name='category_list'),
    url(r'^(?P<category>[-\w]+)/(?P<slug>[-\w]+)/$', 
        views.content_or_sub_category, name='choice')
    ...
]
```

For example, say the URL 'example.com/foo/bar' is supposed to redirect. It would match the second url pattern above, get sent to `content_or_sub_category`, which checks whether 'foo' is a valid category or not, and if 'bar' is a valid slug. Upon finding that they're not, it 404s (as in the code below) and doesn't redirect.

In the docs it says

> Each time any Django application raises a 404 error, this middleware checks the redirects database for the requested URL as a last resort.

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/contrib/redirects/

But instead of redirects kicking in any time a 404 is raised it appears to only happen if Django doesn't find a matching pattern.

Is that how it's supposed to be behaving?

I found this question [Raise 404 and continue the URL chain](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1299701/raise-404-and-continue-the-url-chain) about how to resume evaluating the rest of the url patterns if one 404s, but it looks like that's either something you can't or shouldn't do.

The only answer on that question suggested putting some logic in your urls.py, but that would need to check the validity of the URL, and then make the `urlpatterns` list according to whether it's valid or not. I googled and couldn't find a way to do that from within urls.py.

I'm using Django 1.8.

```
class SubCategoryListView(ListView):
    model = Content
    queryset = Content.objects.published()
    paginate_by = 15

    def get_queryset(self):
        qs = super(SubCategoryListView, self).get_queryset()
        if 'category' in self.kwargs:
            if self.kwargs['category'] is not None:
                qs = qs.filter(
                    categories__slug__contains=self.kwargs['category'])
        return qs

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super(SubCategoryListView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)

        if 'category' in self.kwargs and self.kwargs['category'] is not None:
            context['category'] = get_object_or_404(Category,
                                                    slug=self.kwargs[
                                                            'category'])
return context

...

def content_or_sub_category(self, **kwargs):
    sub_category = get_object_or_false(Category.objects.sub_categories(),
                                       slug=kwargs['slug'])
    content = get_object_or_false(Content.objects.published(),
                                  slug=kwargs['slug'])
    if content:
        return ContentDetailView.as_view()(self, **kwargs)
    if sub_category:
        return ContentListView.as_view()(self,
                                         **{'category': kwargs['category'],
                                            'sub_category': kwargs['slug']})
    raise Http404
```

Some redirects that don't work:

```
/46421 --> /economy/has-prime-minister-broken-promise-tax-credits/
/are-living-standards-on-the-rise --> /economy/are-living-standards-rise/
/articles/nhs_budget_cut-28646    --> /economy/has-nhs-budget-been-cut/
```

But something like this does work:

```
/health/live/2015/jan/number_12_hour_wait_hospital_bed_accident_emergency-38409 --> /health/spike-numbers-waiting-12-hours-e-hospital-bed/
```

Comment: The middleware works on any 404, not just when a pattern isn't found. Can you show the db entries for your redirects?

Comment: That's what I thought, considering what the docs say. Added some examples, can't really show them all because there's over 6000.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure what `return ContentDetailView.as_view()(self, **kwargs)` is, but in general if you want to redirect, you would use something along the lines of:

```
return redirect(reverse('category_list', args=[ARG1, ARG2]))
```

Where "category_list" is the name of the url pattern, and ARG1 & ARG2 are the arguments you want in the url.

Comment: No problem! If this was the correct answer, be sure to click the check mark on the left of my answer, so that anyone who stumbles on this thread will know what to do

Comment: Not exactly, `return ContentDetailView.as_view()(self, **kwargs)` was working, but your version is clearer. The thing that's _not_ working is redirecting from a page's old url to its new one using the redirects app.